# System.currentTimeMillis() returns wrong date

Tags: android, time, timestamp, sharedpreferences, unix-timestamp

I am trying to save the current time into shared preferences but for some reason the current time is of by a ridiculous amount, in the far future year of `47486`.

I have checked the date settings on the device itself and the date there is correct and I cannot find a problem like this anywhere. I am hoping someone here may be able to help me.

Here is where the problem is:

```
public static void setLastSyncSucceeded(final Context context) {
     SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
     long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     sp.edit().putLong(PREF_LAST_SYNC_SUCCEEDED, currentTime).commit();
}
```

So basically while I was debugging i noticed that `currentTime` is `1436374427923` which is `Tue, 23 Nov 47486 00:38:43 GMT`...

Comment: See http://www.epochconverter.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value you have there is milliseconds (as in `currentTimeMillis`) and you're treating it as if it were seconds.

Divide it by a thousand (i.e., turn it into seconds) and you get the much more sensible value of `Wed, 08 Jul 2015 16:53:47 GMT`.

Comment: thank you that was the problem i didnt notice that the websites i was using to convert the time were converting from seconds and not milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

returns the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

UTC is the common time standart in the world. It is also considered as GMT(Greenwich Mean Time) -not exacly the same thing-.

So if you are in different time zone then you should take this into account.

Comment: The Question was about the year `47486`, not the time zone.

Comment: @BasilBourque Have you tried to convert 1436374427923 into Date it is valid date and time. Obviously 47486 is the mistake of the op. We don't know how he tried to convert to date.

Answer (score 0):

If you want get a formatted date from current milliseconds then you can do something like this:

```
long yourmilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm"); //Play with the parameters to get different results
Date resultdate = new Date(yourmilliseconds);
String formattedActualDate = sdf.format(resultdate);
```

or easily:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm");
String formattedActualDate = sdf.format(new Date());
```

And finally:

```
public static void setLastSyncSucceeded(final Context context) {
     SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
     long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     sp.edit().putLong(PREF_LAST_SYNC_SUCCEEDED, formattedActualDate).commit();
}
```